# Password in Rubik's cube

Tags: password, rubiks-cube

Alice needs a strong password, but she has terrible memory - so she have decided to hide it in a Rubik's cube she happens to carry around all the time

- Alice starts with a solved 5x5x5 Rubiks Cube
- She does exactly 7 moves (rotation of one slice by 90/180/270 degrees)
- After those moves she reads the password as starting letters of color names on the side with white center, read row by row from top to bottom, where the side with red center is in the front side.

> It will look like "wwrgrbbwwwbowowooyyywyoor"

**Can you get Alice password just by knowing the side with red center?**

[image: ryrwrryrgrryrwrgbbrbbbbbb]

Comment: I take it that the image has nothing to do with the string given??

Comment: the given string is just an example, unrelated to the image. The image has its associated string as 'alt' text

Comment: Can you confirm the colour scheme? Is it
U=white F=red, R=blue, D=yellow, B=orange, L=green
? And is the red face we are given in that orientation, i.e. with the white-centred face adjacent to the top edge of the image?

Comment: It is a standard rubik cube, with no info given about final orientation - it should be obvious from the moves

Comment: There are several single moves which affect only white side but not red side. There are also several *series of moves* which leave red completely unaffected, but yield different white sides. Seeing the red side will absolutely reduce the entropy of the white side, but there is no distinct password. For instance, just rotate the slice with orange middle. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: @Carl - there is exactly 7 moves being done, try to modify the red side to this state and do a serie of moces that affects white side only.

Comment: @Paul find the state of the white side (white middle) based on the hints. Start with solved cube find the 7 moves that get the red side into this state.

Comment: @Hurda yeah, after carefully reading the question again I got it, hence I deleted my old comment. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Hurda Alright, I thought you were asking about the general case, i.e., given ANY red side. So the question is... is there a distinct series of moves that end up in your particular configuration that has length exactly $7$.

Comment: @Carl yes, exactly. Thanks for claryfing for others

Comment: Can you please reconfirm that Alice is using the same kind of cube I have: when Alice looks at the blue-red-yellow corner of the solved cube, do the colours run in clockwise or counterclockwise order?

Comment: Western color sheme https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/japanese-western-color-schemes/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the description in the question, I wasn't able to decide which way is "up" on the white side, so I would have to take four guesses, but I think the cube looks like this:

> [image]

This is probably unique, my Most Rigorous proof is that it was pretty damn difficult to get there in 7 moves :-)

Here are the 7 moves: (with the cube upside down, because that's how [the simulator I used](https://www.grubiks.com/puzzles/rubiks-professors-cube-5x5x5/) places the initial cube.)

> [image]

The third and the fourth move can be done in a different order, of course, but that still produces an identical cube. Any other changes to the sequence would not produce the required red side. The only other variations I found that get anywhere are

1. Constructing the pattern the other side up
2. Omitting the second move
3. Both of the above

Sadly, it is only possible to get a (partially) mirrored version of the required pattern in any of those ways. (Proof: spent *way* too much time trying to make it work.)

Therefore, if there is another way to construct the red face in 7 moves, it has to be with some completely different moves altogether.

Comment: Best. Proof. Ever.

Comment: very proof. much rigorous.

Comment: How did you make the gif? That's so cool! :P

Answer (score 0):

It is better if Alice stores her password on a 3x3, as we can

> Guess of the centers, as they are fixed, and find out the other pieces, by tracing the 7 turns, and just having one face as the input after that.

In the case of a 5x5, it gets tricky, as

> The number of possible slice moves increases, and also the the centers of two kinds (x centers at the corner fringe, and + centers at the edge fringe), cannot be deduced, even if you are given the information of 5 sides, and one side is hidden.

The reason being

> That there are nifty amount of 2-cycles that can be put up on this centers, making them untraceable unless we have the visual of all the 6 sides.[image: 5x5 center information]

On the other hand

> A 3x3 [image: 3x3 cube], has 4x10^17 possibilies, letting us store even a 10 digit ASCII code password quite easily, if we form a map between each state, and a string of ASCII characters (this will be a tedious task), but a 3x3, or multiple 3x3, solves the problem.

If your password is quite long,

> Then there is one more fantastic solution, you can have 2 cube states added onto a single 3x3 cube : eg, U D M B' U' S R' S' R U B M' U' D' + F E F2 R' S' R S R' E' R F, and you can retrieve it by some computational factoring algorithm, the same way we try to factorise big prime numbers during encryption.

See this video for more clarity on what I mean by adding cube states:
[Adding cube states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZfrWhLR3jQ)